# Login to Orocommerce Back-Office

Tags: orocommerce

I have recently installed "OroCommerce Community Edition with Demo Data", to AWS, using [these instructions](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/demo-environment/aws/). I am able to successfully log into the storefront app (using the sample username: AmandaRCole@example.org,  provided in the above link). However, I am not able to log into the Back-Office (via admin/admin). Is there a different username/password combo, set as the default for the Back-Office app?

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS instance id is used as the default admin user password.

Looks like there is a mistake in the documentation. The team will fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use Instance ID as password.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the documentation page is still out of date and says to use admin/admin for login/password. Using the instance id for the password worked for me!

[image]